# AWS - How to open a command prompt in my auto scaled windows 2016 AMI to launch my node server

Tags: node.js, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have setup auto scaling policy to launch an windows 2016 AMI EC2 instance once certain thresholds are crossed.
After windows is booted up, I want to open command prompt, change to a particular directory and start my node http server.

I have specified the following command in user data while setting up launch configuration.

**start cmd /k cd c:\pizza-luvrs-master|npm start**

My instances are getting launched but the commands are not getting executed!
the problem is in lauching command window itself. rest of the command is fine.

any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the image you use in your auto scaling group is working correctly, you can copy your command into a `.cmd` file and then add it to the Task Scheduler. You should set the trigger to "At Startup".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try that